# Get ranking of a clicked link

Tags: javascript, html, seo

Is it possible to retrieve the rank of my website when visitors clicks on the link to my site on Google? It would be interesting for me to understand where my site appears on the Google search result for different search queries - ie. was my site first, second, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't.

You might be able to get the referer (but Google are switching to SSL searches for logged in users, so that information will be unavailable), but even if you did the results are shuffled on a per-user basis.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.

**But:**

You have the possibility to check your serp ranking with other tools:

*For example:*

http://www.serprank.com/

http://www.sitemapdoc.com/serp-rank.aspx